# Data explorer queries are missing an author attribution

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, licensing

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) queries are licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), like user contributions on normal sites. Yet query pages on SEDE do not have any user attribution whatsoever. Queries should link to their author's profile, like posts and post histories do. At the moment, SE displaying SEDE queries is technically illegal.

Comment: I know what you mean in that they aren't displayed when viewing the queries themselves, but you know they are visible in the [list of queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured)?

Comment: @JasonPlank I know they are, and also from authors' profiles. But that meets neither the letter nor the spirit of the license.

Comment: We're not ignoring this, it's just that Waffles is out on vacation for a bit, I'll ping him to take a look at this when he gets settled back in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now complete ... you get plenty of attribution.

The query show page shows who created the query and who last edited it.

The edit query page shows who created each revision.